# Netbeans installer stopped, can't install or uninstall

Tags: installation, netbeans

Netbeans 7.3 install was interrupted, I don't have /usr/local/netbeans, I can't find the app or uninstall files. Installing again says component has been installed.

Comment: Download from here https://netbeans.org/downloads/ and install manually.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did.

Answer (score 0):

`Applications` -> `Programming` -> `Netbeans`